# Wrong use of eval() in asp.net ascx property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, properties

I have my own **ascx control** called **MyButton**. **MyButton** have these properties:

```
public string ImageUrl;
[Bindable(true)]
public string NavigateUrl;
public string Text;
```

I need to bind text to **NavigateUrl** property in my **GridView** and I do it like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CategoriesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="CategoriesSqlDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <cc:MyButton ID="ShowMyButton" runat="server" Text="Show" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></cc:MyButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But When I use **Eval** function to property **NavigateUrl** property is still null.

Do you have any suggestion what I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like some debugging is in order.

Comment: well,try like this code,hope it helps : '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>'

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work too..